# A returned list is not returning the data

Tags: c#, list

I have two classes, one which is to contain a list (Student) and the other is a menu program which uses it (Program).

When I return the list from the Student Class, it is returning`System.Collections.Generic.List'1[2015Assignment.StudentClass]`.

Why is the data not being returned?

It is built in the Student Class like this:

```
namespace 2015Assignment
{
    class StudentClass
    {
        private string StoredStudentName;
        public List<StudentClass> GetName()
        {
            /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
             * Hard Programming the list of students                                *
             *----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            List<StudentClass> ListOfStudents = new List<StudentClass>();
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Jane"));
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Alex"));
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Mike"));
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("James"));
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Julia"));
            return ListOfStudents;
        }

        public StudentClass(string StudentName)
        {
            StoredStudentName = StudentName;
        }
    }
}
```

And called/written to the console in the Program Class like this:

```
StudentClass studentClass = new StudentClass("");
static void Main()
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        List<StudentClass> ListOfStudents = program.studentClass.GetName().ToList();
        ListOfStudents.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}", i.GetName()));
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You may had more tags to your question please

Comment: Normally, you dont write `Class` at the end of a class...

Comment: Your `GetName` should either return a single `string`(the name of a single Student) or being renamed to `GetAllStudents`. However, even if you would return a single `Student` you need to override `ToString` meaningfully, then `Console.WriteLine` would output the name of the `Student`

Comment: you're trying to access private property, make StoredStudentName public and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Maxim Goncharuk is absolutely correct regarding why you see `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[2015Assignment.StudentClass]` printed in the console. Your `GetName()` method returns `List<StudentClass>` and you see its string representation.

I would rewrite your `StudentClass` as:

```
internal class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Student(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public static List<Student> GenerateStudents()
    {
        var students= new List<Student>();
        students.Add(new Student("Jane"));
        students.Add(new Student("Alex"));
        students.Add(new Student("Mike"));
        students.Add(new Student("James"));
        students.Add(new Student("Julia"));
        return students;
    }
}
```

Several reasons:

- You should not include type information into your names. Thus, `StudentClass` should be just `Student`
- `GetName()` method name is not a very good name for something that generates data. Confusing.
- There is no need for `private` field for name in your case. Just use a simple `public` property. If you want to prevent outside code from changing `Name`, just make the `set` accessor `private`: `public string Name { get; private set; }`
- There is no need for a `Student` instance to generate data. Make sense to make this method `static`

I would also rewrite your Program class as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var students = Student.GenerateStudents();
        students.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}", i.Name));

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Reasons:

- I don't see why you need to keep an instance of `Student` (`StudentClass` in your original code) as part of your `Program` class. Local variable fits better if you just want to write something to console
- Generally, it's not a good practice to instantiate your `Program` class. It should serve just an entrance to your application and should be used by framework only

Comment: Thanks for this - it's really cleared a lot up for me, as well as the answer from @Maxim Goncharuk. I'm fairly new to c#, and haven't got used to the standards and good practices yet, so sorry for confusing you all!

Comment: @B.Halsey no problem. Glad that it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

You call method `i.GetName()` which return `List<StudentClass>` and `Console.WriteLine` call `ToString()`, so you have `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[2015Assignment.StudentClass]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class StudentClass
{
    private string _storedStudentName;
    public static List<StudentClass> GetStudents()
    {
        List<StudentClass> ListOfStudents = new List<StudentClass>();
        ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Jane"));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Alex"));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Mike"));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("James"));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Julia"));
        return ListOfStudents;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _storedStudentName;
        }
    }

    public StudentClass(string StudentName)
    {
        _storedStudentName = StudentName;
    }
}
```

Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<StudentClass> ListOfStudents = StudentClass.GetStudents();
        ListOfStudents.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}", i.Name));
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactored a few things in your code. Your code actually didn't make a lot of sense (or maybe its just me)

```
//namespace can not start with a number
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //You need to define the list in your host program, not inside the class itself    
            List<StudentClass> ListOfStudents = new List<StudentClass>();
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Jane"));
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Alex"));
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Mike"));
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("James"));
            ListOfStudents.Add(new StudentClass("Julia"));


            ListOfStudents.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}", i.GetName()));
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

    //changed the class to public so you can access it.
    public class StudentClass
    {
        private string _storedStudentName;

        public string GetName()
        {
            return _storedStudentName;
        }

        public StudentClass(string studentName)
        {
            _storedStudentName = studentName;
        }
    }
}
```